# Вынести загрузчик Windows 7-10 с винта на внешнюю USB флешку

Tags: windows, grub

Как правильно вынести загрузчик Windows на внешнюю флешку и пускать его через syslinux/grub ? т.е. использовать внешнюю флешку как аппаратный ключ защиты на запуск системы (от малолетних кулкацкеров)

Comment: загрузчик не вынесешь. но можно отключить активный раздел. или можешь запускать через `Plop Boot Manager` Можно поставить пароль на grub2 и скрыть определённые пункты (флешка не потребуется). Или для grub `chainloader +1`. Но всёравно загрузчик можно переустановить диском восстановления системы или программой